# MDK-ARM C error: expression must have a constant value

Tags: c

i'm writing an `embedded C` code based on state machine in `MDK-ARM` environment which uses `RealView` (ARMCC based) compiler.

IDE generates an error:

> error:  #28: expression must have a constant value.

A part of code is following:

```
struct wspace
{
    struct netimer period;
    struct nequeue deferred;
    struct nevent *deferred_queue_storage[EPA_EEPROM_QUEUE_SIZE];
    struct nepa *producer;
    struct event_i2c_transfer transfer;
    uint32_t i2c_retry;
    uint8_t i2c_buffer[3];
    uint32_t address;
    uint8_t *raw_buffer;
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t idx;
    uint32_t max_size;
    uint32_t dev_id;
};

static naction state_init_eeprom(struct nsm * sm, const struct nevent * event) {
    struct wspace * ws = nsm_wspace(sm);

    switch (event->id) {
        case NSM_INIT : {
            struct nequeue_define deferred_queue =
            **NEQUEUE_DEF_INIT(ws->deferred_queue_storage, sizeof(ws->deferred_queue_storage));** // this is the line pointed by compiler

            netimer_init(&ws->period);
            nequeue_init(&ws->deferred, &deferred_queue);
            ws->transfer.super          = g_default_event;
            ws->transfer.super.producer = nepa_get_current();
            ws->transfer.dev_id         = EEPROM_I2C_ID;
            ws->transfer.timeout_ms     = EEPROM_I2C_TIMEOUT_MS;
            ws->max_size                = 8 * 1024;
            ws->dev_id                  = EEPROM_I2C_ID;

            return (naction_transit_to(sm, state_idle));
        }
        default : {
            return (naction_ignored());
        }
    }
}
```

**important definitions:**

```
#define NEQUEUE_SIZEOF(elements)                                                
    (sizeof(struct nevent * [elements]))

#define NEQUEUE_DEF_INIT(storage, size)                                         
    {storage, size}     

struct nequeue_define
{
    struct nevent ** storage;/**<@brief Allocated memory storage   */
    size_t size;   /**<@brief Size of queue in bytes     */
};


struct nequeue
{
    struct nqueue               queue;
    #if (CONFIG_REGISTRY == 1)
    ncore_reg                   min;
    #endif
    #if (CONFIG_API_VALIDATION == 1)
    unsigned int                signature;
    #endif
};
```

Everything i found on this topic is related with the fact that the constant variable cannot be assigned to the element of an array or member of structure as initializer even if it is initialized before.

Does anyone have idea how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use contents of variables in constant expressions, and your struct initalizer is constant expression.

While `sizeof(ws->deferred_queue_storage)` is OK, since it's value can be determined at compile time; `ws->deferred_queue_storage` is invalid, because contents of that variable can be anything.

Solution is to use assignment after allocation:

```
struct nequeue_define deferred_queue;
deferred_queue.storage = ws->deferred_queue_storage;
deferred_queue.size = sizeof(ws->deferred_queue_storage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler complains about variable usage in the `NEQUEUE_DEF_INIT(ws->deferred_queue_storage, sizeof(ws->deferred_queue_storage));`

You could use it like `NEQUEUE_DEF_INIT(100, 200)` but not with variables as macro arguments since in this case it must be known before compiling.

Comment: thanks, i supposed too, but not sure. Still not clear how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think I should pass pointer as a first member of structure but don't know how to do it? Idea seems ok, but could you be more precise?if you carefully look at wspace struct you can see that  struct nevent *deferred_queue_storage[EPA_EEPROM_QUEUE_SIZE] is arrea of pointers, where each pointer represent one event buffer. What i temporary doing is trying to port software from GCC to Keil RealView compiler. This NEQUEUE_DEF_INIT should be only queue initializer.

Comment: I think that you just have to avoid NEQUEUE_DEF_INIT macro. Have you tried to set storage and size like user694733 suggested?

Comment: Yes i did, and still have the same problem.

Comment: I've got the problem solved. As user694733 said structure should be initialized like he wrote. And solution of problem look like this: struct nequeue_define deferred_queue;
     deferred_queue.storage = ws->deferred_queue_storage;
     deferred_queue.size = sizeof(ws->deferred_queue_storage);

Comment: Just got it should not even compile with .nevent since it is declaration not a name...